# Why does the_content() show nothing while echoing the content works just fine?

Tags: wordpress

I am doing this:

```
$faq = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'my_faq', 'page_id'=>$faq_id));
if ($faq->have_posts()) : while ($faq->have_posts()) : $faq->the_post();
    $faq->the_content();
    //echo $faq->post->post_content;
    print_r($faq->post);
    endwhile;
endif;
```

I know I will only ever get a max of one result so the loop is overkill but I added it in just to test. In any event, when I print the post it prints the correct post and when I use the echo statement above I get my post printed just fine but when I use the_content() as shown above, suddenly all I get is an empty page.

Simple question: Why?

Comment: Did you try writing just the_content() instead of $faq->the_content(); ?

Comment: Is it network wordpress site?
Are you using polylang plug-in?

Comment: remove `$fag->` from `$faq->the_content();`

Comment: @VasimShaikh yes, it is a network site. does that matter? :O Please elaborate! As for that plugin you mentioned, no, I am not using third party plugins on my site apart from WooCommerce. I wrote everything except Owl Carousel myself. This error is happening when I try to show a FAQ page inside a tab inside the Woo product description. I am busy making a VERY customised theme.  I tried removing $faq-> and just use the_content() but that printed the content of a completely different page which I have no idea how it got fetched... I can try again, sure. but it definitely didn't work before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand WHY the first time around when I tried doing so I managed to print the correct post's content but the_content() posted the contents of my site's default landing page... but for whatever the reason it seems to be working now.

Like Stender and KomalR said, the solution was simply to call the global the_content() and not the query's the_content() method. This seems a bit counter-intuitive but at least it works so as long as you know that is what you should do then I guess that is all there is to it...

It works just fine now. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$faq = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'my_faq', 'p'=>$faq_id));
if ($faq->have_posts()) 
    while ( $faq->have_posts() ) : $faq->the_post();
    the_content();    
    endwhile;
endif;
```